# implementing a request using retrofit2 android

Tags: android, retrofit2

Here is a successful request on postman which all the request parts shown in the image which I am trying to implement in retrofit2 [image]
Here is my code trying to implement it

```java
public interface APIService {
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload_operator_data.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part profile_image
            , @Query("jwt") String jwt);
}
```

```java
public class APIClient {

   private  static Retrofit retrofit;


   public static Retrofit getClient(String url)
   {
       if(retrofit==null)
       {
           retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
       }
       return retrofit;
   }
}
```

```java
public class APIUtils {
    public static final String URL ="https://tsaw.tech/AppApi/Operator/";
    public static APIService getService() {
        return APIClient.getClient(URL).create(APIService.class);
    }
}
```

And here is the request:

```java
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestBody);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = mService.uploadImage(fileToUpload, JWT);
        Log.d(TAG, "The requestSent:" + call.request().body());

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Image upload on response message: " + response.message());
                Log.d(TAG, "Image upload on response body: " + response.body());
                Log.d(TAG, "Image upload on response string: " + response.toString());


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(profile_form.this, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "Image upload on Failure: " + t.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

And the log output is

```
2020-07-16 23:12:58.401 13078-13078/com.example.tsaw D/profile_form: Image upload on response message: Unauthorized
2020-07-16 23:12:58.402 13078-13078/com.example.tsaw D/profile_form: Image upload on response body: null
2020-07-16 23:12:58.402 13078-13078/com.example.tsaw D/profile_form: Image upload on response string: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized, url=https://tsaw.tech/AppApi/Operator/upload_operator_data.php?jwt=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9leGFtcGxlLm9yZyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxMzU2OTk5NTI0LCJuYmYiOjEzNTcwMDAwMDAsImRhdGEiOnsOo2BZao}
```

I really don't why postman request is successful and this retrofit2 request is not.

Here is the full activity for more details:

```java
package com.example.tsaw.javafile;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.FileUtils;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.tsaw.R;
import com.example.tsaw.javafile.API.APIService;
import com.example.tsaw.javafile.API.APIUtils;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

public class profile_form extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = profile_form.class.getSimpleName();
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    Button open_camera, Submit;
    ImageView profile_pic;
    String imagpath;
    String JWT;
    APIService mService;
    File file;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_form);
        open_camera = findViewById(R.id.Open_Camera);
        profile_pic = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        Submit = findViewById(R.id.upload);
        mService = APIUtils.getService();

//        final String image = getStringImage(bitmap);


        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Token", MODE_PRIVATE);
        JWT = prefs.getString("Token", null);

        open_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showFileChooser();
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Jwt" + JWT);

        Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                uploadImage();
            }
        });

    }

    private void    uploadImage() {
        final String Token = JWT.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "The current token: " + Token);

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("profile_image", file.getName(), requestBody);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = mService.uploadImage(fileToUpload, Token);

        Log.d(TAG, "The requestSent:" + call.request().url());


        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Image upload on response message: " + response.message());
                Log.d(TAG, "Image upload on response body: " + response.body());
                Log.d(TAG, "Image upload on response string: " + response.toString());


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(profile_form.this, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "Image upload on Failure: " + t.getMessage());

            }
        });

    }


    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "File not found ", LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            try {
                InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

                profile_pic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                file = createFileFromBitmap(this,bitmap,"profile_pic");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Uri imageURI = data.getData();

            Log.d(TAG, "Image selected successfully: " + imageURI.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "Image selected successfully: " + file);
        }
    }



    public File createFileFromBitmap(Context context,Bitmap bitmap,String filename) throws IOException {
        //create a file to write bitmap data
        File f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), filename);
        f.createNewFile();

//Convert bitmap to byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 1 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

//write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(bitmapdata);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        return f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing the code creating the request to

```java
      HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("jwt", toRequestBody(token));
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"),file);

        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("profile_image", file.getName(), requestBody);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = mService.uploadImage(fileToUpload, map);
```

and the APIinterface to:

```java
public interface APIService {
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload_operator_data.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part profile_image
            ,  @PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> partMap);
}
```